# How to upload multiple files simultaneously from inside GridView of ASP.NET Web Forms using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I have a **GridView** and some columns in it. I have created a template column inside the GridView, and in it a **file upload control** is placed.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
    <ItemTemplate>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The GridView is binded with data so that it has multiple rows. These is a button given below the GridView and on the the button click I want to upload all the files of the file upload control (at the same time) to the server.

I have seen a similar tutorial on [Multiple File Upload](https://www.yogihosting.com/multi-file-upload-with-progress-bar-in-asp-net/) which does a similar thing, only difference is that I have not one but multiple files to upload.

I want to use JavaScript or jQuery to do it.

Please help me in this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to allow uploading multiple files in your file upload control like this:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

Or:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" Multiple="Multiple" runat="server" />
```

Use `HttpFileCollection` class to retrieve all the files to upload:

```
    try
    {
        HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];              
            if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" +
                  Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));                      
            }              
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle your exception here
    }
```

For details, you can take a look at [here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=68)

Comment: the pleasure is all mine :)